# Memory management of lists in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-management

I can't seem to understand following behavior in python:

```
x = [0, [1,2,3,4,5],[6]]
y = list(x)
y[0] = 10
y[2][0] = 7
print x
print y
```

It Outputs:

```
[0, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [7]]
[10, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [7]]
```

Why is second index of x and y updated and only the first index of y?

Comment: ahh shallow copies and interning of `int`s

Answer (score 6):

This happens because `list(x)` creates a *shallow* copy of the list `x`. Some of the elements in `x` are lists themselves. No copies are created for them; they are instead passed as references. In this way `x` and `y` end up having a reference to the same list as an element.

If you want to create a *deep copy* of x (i.e. to also copy the sublists) use:

```
import copy
y = copy.deepcopy(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python,sequence are divided into mutable sequence,which can be changed after they are created, and immutable sequence.For immutable sequences(string,Unicode,Tuples),Python make a copy for them.For mutable sequences(Lists,Byte Arrays), Python make a reference for them.

So if you change x ,y will also be changed as as they have a reference to the same list.

[The standard type hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy)